# How does on include the PCL library to an existing ros package code?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, include, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert my code from using a vector of particles to a proper point cloud implementation. I want to use the octree module of PCL for radius based searches. However, when compiling the code, I get undefined references to Octree library functions.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with ROS-melodic. I tried including PCL-1.8 under /usr/include in my CMakeLists.txt file as well as downloading and adding PCL-1.9.1 under my ros package (which crashes my PC during compilation). I am also not able to `find_package()` the pcl library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(points_reader)

add_compile_options(-std=c++17)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_DEPS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  message_runtime
  roscpp
  rospy
  toposens_pointcloud
  toposens_driver
  toposens_msgs
  tf
  # pcl
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  sensor_msgs
)

find_package(
  catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_DEPS}
)

############
## Config ##
############

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_DEPS}
)

################
## Executable ##
################

add_subdirectory(external/pcl)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(
  include 
  external
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/line.cpp
  src/fitness_evaluator.cpp
  src/points_reader.cpp
  src/points_mapper.cpp
  src/bounding_box.cpp
  src/points_publisher.cpp
)

add_dependencies(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  # ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg
  ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

add_executable(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  src/points_reader_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
)

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
  COMPONENT main
)

##########
## Test ##
##########

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334548/how-does-on-include-the-pcl-library-to-an-existing-ros-package-code?/) by [Inshal240](https://answers.ros.org/users/46639/inshal240/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-04**:
You should not need the `link_directories(..)`. I would also suggest to remove everything related to your "external PCL" from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

If PCL 1.8 is sufficient (in Melodic), depending on `pcl_ros` should import all required dependencies (including PCL itself).

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-10-04**:
And I'm a bit confused, you stated, you are using Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS melodic, I shouldn't it either be kinetic or Ubuntu 18.04?

**Comment by [Inshal240](https://answers.ros.org/users/46639/inshal240/) on 2019-10-04**:
I will double-check on the Ubuntu version. I believe you may be right about it being 18.04

EDIT: It was. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the cause of the issue. I was getting the undefined reference issue because the PointT template argument I was using for `OctreePointCloudSearch` was included after the octree's header file. So it tried to instantiate the template using a class that didn't exist. Hence the reference errors.

I removed all the external pcl references from my header file and stuck to what the tutorial showed and it still compiles.

Thank you everyone for your help and time!

---

Originally posted by [Inshal240](https://answers.ros.org/users/46639/inshal240/) with karma: 16 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0